# Involute of a Curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, plane-curves, curvature

A string of length ℓ is attached to the point γ(0) of a unit-speed plane
curve γ(s). Show that when the string is wound onto the curve while
being kept taught, its endpoint traces out the curve
ι(s) = γ(s)+(ℓ − s)γ˙(s),
where 0  0 for all s. Show
that the signed curvature of ι is 1/(ℓ − s).

I cant get to why the formula has (ℓ − s) and not ℓ and also i cant find the signed curvature since if i take the second derivative of ι(s) ill get  a third degree derivative of γ(s)